# How to list usage hour for each EC2 instances

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to know for a given period, example 2017 January, the hours each EC2 instances ran, example:

```
id        type         hours
i-123      m3.large       260
i-129      m3.large       100
i-126      m3.large       280
```

How could I extract this from AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this information from your [Billing Reports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports.html), but you will need to turn on [Detailed Billing Reports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports.html#DetailedBillingReport).

This detailed level of reporting is **not back-dated**, so you can only obtain this level of information *after* activating Detailed Billing.

I would also recommend [Tagging Your Amazon EC2 Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html), which can provide richer information in the billing reports (eg grouping by Cost Center or Project).

Comment: So basically by default I don't have any other option than the detailed billing to know the hours that my instances have been running?

Comment: That is correct. Billing is a separate entity to the one that actually runs the instances. (Actually, you can find the running time of a currently *Running* instance, just not previously-running ones.)

Comment: where can I find the running hours of a currently running instnaces? Inside the description tab i can only see the launch time (and i don't think it referes to the running time)

Comment: You are correct. There is a Launch Time from which you could calculate the time that it has been running. When an instance is stopped and started, the Launch Time is the most recent Start time.